# Regex: Exclude word with word `-map` before `.scss`

Tags: regex

Regex to select filenames which is not preceded by `-map` before `.scss`.

```
something-something.scss -> Match
something-map.scss -> Don't match
something.scss -> Match
```

Tried

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?!-map).scss
```

but not working. It select all files.

Comment: @Maroun - It does not select the `something-something.scss`.

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z]+(?:-(?!map\b))?[a-zA-Z]*\.scss$`  https://regex101.com/r/KQLM0p/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the negative lookbehind:

```
.*(?<!map)\.scss
```

**The explanation:** It tells the regex engine to temporarily step backwards in the string, to check if the text inside the lookbehind can be matched there. `(?<!a)b` matches a `“b”` that is not preceded by an `“a”`, using negative lookbehind. It doesn’t match cab, but matches the b (and only the b) in bed or debt. `(?<=a)b` (positive lookbehind) matches the b (and only the b) in cab, but does not match bed or debt.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [negative-lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Change your regex to:

```
(?<!-map)\.scss
```

This matches all `.scss` files that are not preceded by "-map".